# Breaking SQL columns into their own rows in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

How would I go about doing this in SQL?  I have a table that has two columns holding data that I need separate rows for.  An example probably works best here.

This is the current structure of my table:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║  CustID   ║  Title  ║ Plays ║ Shares ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ Sony      ║ Movie 1 ║   123 ║    224 ║
║ Sony      ║ Movie 2 ║   344 ║    766 ║
║ Universal ║ Movie 3 ║   334 ║    866 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

What I need is to split the 'plays' and 'shares' events into separate rows in my select statement, like so:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║  CustID   ║  Title  ║ Events ║ Type  ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Sony      ║ Movie 1 ║    123 ║ play  ║
║ Sony      ║ Movie 1 ║    224 ║ share ║
║ Sony      ║ Movie 2 ║    334 ║ play  ║
║ Sony      ║ Movie 2 ║    766 ║ share ║
║ Universal ║ Movie 3 ║    334 ║ play  ║
║ Universal ║ Movie 3 ║    866 ║ share ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

I'm essentially doing a SQL pivot, but instead of taking multiple rows and pivoting them into a single one, I'm trying to go the other way.  Is there a good way to do this?  I'm using Postgres 9.x for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cross join to do the unpivot:

```
select t.cust_id, t.title, x.event, x.type
from test t
  cross join lateral (values (plays, 'plays'), (shares, 'shares')) as x(event, type)
order by t.cust_id, t.title;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c2333381b5374b8c109c758a7ba95b2e)

Answer (score 1):

One approach, which should work on any database (including Postgres), would be to use a series of unions to unpivot your data:

```
SELECT CustID, Title, Plays AS Events, 'play' AS "Type" FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT CustID, Title, Shares, 'share' FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CustID, Title, Events;
```

### Demo